# Use id made from latitude and longitude

Tags: mysql, primary-key

Is it possible to use in my database an id (primary key) made from a localization (latitude and longitude) ? My formula is like this :

```
public long getKeyValue() {
    return Long.valueOf((intLatitude + 90 * 1000) + "" + (intLongitude + 180 * 1000));
}
```

`intLatitude` and `intLongitude` both are multiplied by 1000 and rounded. I respectively add 90 and 180 to remap the origin in order to handle negative coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the given approach you are going to have problems because of ambiguity. For example 123 could be latitude 1 longitude 23 or latitude 12 longitude 3. You should pad with zeros or use a separator.

Why do you bother mapping the two to a single value? Most database systems permit compound primary keys so you can use the pair (lat, lon) directly as a key.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample, my bad